# how to separate if and else in matlab

Tags: matlab, entropy

let us consider following code

```
function averageentropy=calculate(f,y)
count1=0;
count0=0;
n=length(f);
n1=0;
n0=0;
 entrop1=0;
  entrop2=0;
bigp=sum(f)/n;
for i=1:n 
     if f(i)==1 && y(i)==1
         count1=count1+1;
     end
end
 for i=1:n
     if  f(i)==0 && y(i)==1
          count0=count0+1;
     end
 end
for i=1:n
     if f(i)==1
          n1=n1+1;
     end
end
 for i=1:n 
     if f(i)==0
         n0=n0+1;
     end
 end
 smallpplus=count1/n1;
 smallpminus=count0/n0;
 if smallpplus==0
     entrop1=0;
 else
 entrop1=-smallpplus*log2(smallpplus)-(1- smallpplus)*log2(1- smallpplus);
end
  if smallpminus==0
     entrop2=0;
  else
  entrop2=-smallpminus*log2(smallpminus)-(1- smallpminus)*log2(1- smallpminus);

 end 
  averageentropy=bigp*entrop1+(1-bigp)*entrop2
end
```

when I am  running this code, I am getting  0.4056, while in Excel the same procedure returns me approximately 0.91, which means that  there is some error in if and else case, because if I remove if and else, I am getting the same answer to, so what is problem? I am using if and else to avoid  log(0), but there is some problem.

Comment: Have you set break point in the code to see if you go always in the if or the else ?

Comment: Select _all_ of your code in the MATLAB editor and hit CTRL+I.

Comment: What are the inputs? How do you know Wxcel is giving the right answer? If you could show your excel implementation maybe we can help you figure out the difference - the description of what you want to do is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

If f,y are real valued and not integers I would recommend using for example

> abs(f(i)-1) <= eps

where eps is a 'small number' (e.g `eps = 1e-5`)
instead of

> f(i)==1

On a side note, you could write this part of your code:

```
for i=1:n 
     if f(i)==1 && y(i)==1
         count1=count1+1;
     end
end
 for i=1:n
     if  f(i)==0 && y(i)==1
          count0=count0+1;
     end
 end
for i=1:n
     if f(i)==1
          n1=n1+1;
     end
end
 for i=1:n 
     if f(i)==0
         n0=n0+1;
     end
 end
```

more compactly and efficiently by taking advantage of Matlab's vectorized expression capabilities (I preferred to sacrifice some extra lines for the sake of readability):

```
indf1 = f == 1;
indf0 = ~indf1 ;
indy1 = y == 1;
indy0 = ~indy1 ;
count1 = sum(indf1 & indy1) ;
count0 = sum(indf0 & indy1) ;
n1 = sum(indf1);
n0 = sum(indf0);
```

Comment: is it cause  of this?

Comment: Does f or y contain real values or just integers?

Comment: just integers,0 and 1